# Whats a good bike for under $450

Tags: mountain-bike

Looking for a bike for a 17 year old to get from place to place.  On a budget of $450 USD.  What style of bike and how do I find the best deals?

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  You're asking for a product recommendation, and we won't do that because the info gets stale real quick.  How about you ask for "what to look for in a low-end bike?"

Comment: There are a couple of okay answers so far, but they are making assumptions about the type of riding you want to do. I think you need to give us more information before this can be answered properly. Will you be riding on the road/pavement? Always? Sometimes? When going from place to place, might this involve going up any hills? Would you anticipate needing to carry cargo on the bike? Budget constraints will of course come into it, but they're really secondary until you can say what type of bike you want. Same goes for fit.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest Craigslist or a similar source for a used bike. You're likely to find a much better value there than anything you can get new.

Comment: I think you do need to know more about bikes than the OP seems to, to avoid the two main anonymous second hand bike pitfalls: stolen and junk.

Answer (score 1):

A good bike is one on which the rider is comfortable, and prepared to ride it.  Doesn't matter if its a $50 or $5000 ride, fit and comfort is everything.

You don't need to buy new, although the current generation of teenagers would likely disagree.

The trick is to find a good fit, and involve your teen so its not a punishment.  Do you ride personally?  Ride with your teen now and again.  Take your teen window shopping, and browse the local ebay listings or what-have-you.

Personally, avoid black-painted bikes because they're stolen more, and harder to see in the dark.

Avoid trendy fixies and single speeds, makes your teen stand out and often they don't want that.

I'd recommend either a boring hard tail MTB or a road bike, depending on where the teen wants to go.

EDIT: You know your teenager, what sort of thing might appeal and what would put them off.  Make a judgement call on frame type by involving your teen.

Comment: Fit is not everything.   A BSO that fits but breaks down and is not serviceable is not a good bike.  Do you have data that a black bike is stolen more?

Comment: @Frisbee A bike that doesn't fit won't be ridden, so it doesn't get the chance to break down.  
As for colour, I used to work at a school and I saw all the "stolen item" reports.  Black bikes were at least half, of 1-3 reports a month.

Answer (score 0):

For value just getting from place to place I would say a used single speed. Single speed keeps the cost down and easy maintenance. For getting from place to place a single speed does the job.

A bike that will take larger tires (like 28mm or 32mm) is a good choice as they deal with bumps better.

Avoid a department store bike or BSO (bicycle shaped object).  What you get is not just low end components but also components that are often hard to find. $400 is probably not enough to get a new named brand from a bike shop.  You need to get more into the $600 for new quality bike.  But even if you were going to speed $600 I would still say used.

Used is your best value. You can find used bikes in great shape for 1/2 the new price or better.  Avoid old bikes (like more than 10 years) as older components can be harder to find and more expensive. Go thru the bike and make sure it is in good running shape. Again single speed is your friend - less to maintain and less to go wrong. If the tires are worn out replace them. If is runs poorly or leaves them stranded they will not like the bike.

Below is a bike I got on CraigsList for $400 and is a solid bicycle. This is what I ride when I need to lock the bike up outside. It is a cyclocross so it will take larger tires.  It is an excellent city bike.
[image]

Don't agree with Criggie a teen would not want a single speed as they would stand out.  I think they would rather ride this than some ratty mountain bike.  I think it has a clean cool factor to it.

Comment: This is fine, but there should be a caveat around this whole answer - that a single-speed bike would actually be appropriate for the terrain the Op intends riding. As the question stands, we don't know if that is true or not.

Comment: @PeteH As the question stands all we have to go on is "place to place". I am taking "place to place" as city travel. That is a very valid and most likely interpretation of "place to place".  Especially given the cost constraint.

Comment: Fine. I guess the point I'm making is that the Op needs to know that a single-speed isn't appropriate for certain types of terrain, before they go out and buy one. They even tagged the question "mountain bike" so right now its not obvious that _any_ road bike would be appropriate for what they want.

Comment: @PeteH I think a reasonable person would interpret my first sentence "For value just getting from place to place" as city travel.  I don't think anyone is going to look at this answer as anything but a recommendation for a value city bike.  I think OP just tagged it because they had to.  And single speed is not terrain specific - I also have a single speed mountain bike.   The question is about a bike on a limited budget and single speed is a very valid answer to that question.